# Detecting addresses via machine learning

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm currently developing a tool aiming to detect addresses (or any pattern, like job, sport team or anything) in a text.

So what I'm currently doing:

1/ Splitting the text in words
2/ Stemming the words

Users can create categories (job, sport team, address...) and will manually assign a sentence to a category.

Each stemmed word of this sentence will be stored in DB, with an updated score (+1)

When I will browse a new document, I will compute for each sentence the score thanks to all words in it.

Example:

**I live in Brown Street, in London**

=> (live+1, Brown +1, Street+1, London+1)

Then next time I see

**I live in Orange Street, in London**
The score will be 3 (live +1, Street+1, London+1) so I can say "this sentence might be an address". If user validates, I update the words (live+1, orange+1, street+1, london+1).
If he says "inaccurate", all words will be downvoted.

I think with more runs, I will be able to detect addresses since "Street" and "London" will have a large score (same for zip code etc)

**My question is:**

First, what do you think about this approach? 
Secondly, context is just ignored with this approach. A sentence with Street & London should have a better score. 
It means if I detect Street & London in the same sentence, we can likely say it's an address.

How can I store this information in a database? I'm currently using a relational database (MySQL), but I'm afraid the size will become huge if I store the link between each word.

Is it what we call a neural network? What is the best way to store it?

Do you have any tips to upgrade my detection algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of assigning a score to each word is reasonable, but I would stick to a more standard machine learning approach.

For instance, you could use a the bag-of-words technique to convert each sentence to a vector. After that, you could fit a classifier to the data (you could try something simple like Naive Bayes. It can work pretty well for text classification, especially if the number of samples is small).

The details depend on the amount of data you have initially and the amount of data you receive from the users daily. If you have a lot of data and the amount of new data is very small, you could just train the model on it and use the new data just for predictions. If you get a lot of new examples, you'd probably do better with a model that supports online learning. There is also a "middle ground" approach: you can retrain your classifier only after you have a batch of new examples (you can play with the size of that batch). This way new samples are taken into account, but you don't need to retrain the model for each new sample.

Once again, I'd start with a standard way to vectorize sentences (for instance, count vectorization) and use a simple classifier that efficiently supports online learning (or at least batch updates).

This way, you need to store only parameters of your model instead of all user input so the size of the data won't grow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will use your solution, bag-of-words and Naive Bayes and see how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

*Is it what we call a neural network?*
Um, No.
A neural network is a model. It is the model you can use to achieve what you want to.

*Do you have any tips to upgrade my detection algorithm?*
Yes. Rather than `feature engineering` and hand coding rules, it is always advisable to use a neural network.

A deep recurrent neural network is what you should try. Deep nets outperform any sophisticated algorithm if you have huge amount of data. ( In your case if you don't have enough data, you can scrap the data online )

In your training phase, you will give neural network a few lines with labels as `true` or `false` (Whether the text represents address lines). After enough training, the network will be able to identify whether a given text represents address lines or not.

With deep learning, the most crucial thing is data. More data beats sophisticated algorithms and good data beats more data.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to know, what is huge? Are talking about 1000, 10000, or maybe 1 million ? Do you have any book/website to recommend to follow your answer ? Thank you!

Comment: I think 25000 examples of both labels would be enough. So in total You would have 50k examples.(40k:10k train to test ratio would be good). Pasting the links of references soon

Comment: 1. Your usuful stuff is from video 44.[Deep Learning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jpIbc20V-k&index=44&list=PLAwxTw4SYaPn_OWPFT9ulXLuQrImzHfOV)
2. A bit mathematical and hard to follow but great foundation. (for you from lecture 7.1)[Machine Learning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enI1YMvCJ34&index=30&list=PLoRl3Ht4JOcdU872GhiYWf6jwrk_SNhz9)
3. The book[Deep Leaning](https://www.amazon.com/Deep-Learning-Adaptive-Computation-Machine/dp/0262035618/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1472485235&sr=8-1&keywords=deep+learning+book) and online [Deep Leaning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/)

Comment: This is not from book or website, its based on personal experience as I persuaded graduation in neural networks in year 1998 along with many projects in mathematical modeling. It's not required to train all patterns in a shot, you can run batched with pre-loading of network parameters. Note that deep learning is nothing but a hoax around a better neural network than classic back-propagation. Always design `custom network` based on parent type like say mix of hopfiled and backpropogation

Answer (score 1):

A deep neural network is indeed a good choice to start with, since feature engineering is done by the network at train time.

However, if you like to try or test a further machine learning method which might suit to your problem then I suggest the use of a *string kernel* combined with the *support vector machine algorithm*. This approach requires in contrast to neural network feature engineering and moreover fundamental knowledge about kernel methods. A first introduction to this might be the Wikipedia article:

[String Kernels on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_kernel)

Answer (score 1):

Lets take following two sentence first one is address but second is not an address but similar statement.

1. I live in **Brown** **Street**, in **London**, LABEL ADDRESS=1
2. I play at **Brown** **Street**, in **London**, LABEL ADDRESS=0

Score matching will fail as both statements will give same score. Also **when stemmed word share categories or labels** this will fail. Even if we use deep learning with *stemmed words* this will fail as both sentence will have same inputs (*or stemmed word*) but labels values are contradicting so *network learning* will collapse event with high amount of learning done.

**Note:** What makes second statement *not-an-address* is identifying word **play** which is not stemmed (*or trained to network input*).

So we should use **deep learning network with all words rather than stemmed ones only and train negative labels also like statements with ADDRESS=1 and similar statements with ADDRESS!=1**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if users can add at anytime a new label? I can't really afford to train my model with a lot of data (maximum 100-200 I guess), what is for you the best way to do this?

Comment: To add new label, you can load parameters of old network **but you've to retrain old patterns also** as network when learning new pattern will forget old pattern. You can design smart tricks where network will not forget past patterns while learning new.